# How do you target (or get) a control in the same row as another control in a XamGrid?

Tags: .net, silverlight, controls, row, infragistics

I am using the `XamGrid` to allow users to edit data. I have several scenarios where the handler of an event on one control in a given editable row must use or target another control in the same row. For example, I want to handle the selection changing of a `ComboEditor` to cause the list of choices in another `ComboEditor` to change. As another example, I'd like a checked checkbox to disable the editing of other controls in the same row.

How would I find or get a reference to a different control in the same row? In general, each control's event arguments are unaware of other controls or that the control is in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in a Silverlight application you would do this using a combination of bindings and a ViewModel object. So for your example a "checked checkbox to disable the editing of other controls in the same row". You would need a property on your ViewModel that the row is bound to that is a bool. Then you would just add a binding to the readonly property on the other columns and bind that to the same property (you might have to reverse the value).